# White page after FB-Login on Mobile WebView in a Wordpress Website

Tags: php, android, wordpress, facebook, cordova

I am using this plugin https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/wp-facebook-login/ and I have Facebook Connect to login and register my users in my Wordpress installation.

I have an app made with cordova and I am using WebView to show the area of my web where the login is requiered.

On mobile browser and desktop browser the fb connect is working fine. However inside the app when I click on Connect with Facebook after inserting the user and password I get a white page.

I saw similar questions regarding to this problem here but I didn't be able to solve. Still white page.

Any idea how can I say my wordpress to load correctly the Facebook Connect inside a webview?

The problem is both Android and iOS.

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP's white screen of death](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475297/phps-white-screen-of-death)

Comment: Still I could not solve this...

Comment: Have you followed the link to the possible duplicate I mentioned and read about PHP's white screen of death? You probably need to enable error reporting, which is discussed on that page. That should reveal much more information about what's going wrong.